# How does EF create the SQL needed to update one million rows in a SQLite table with five million rows? Does it do one by one row updates?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

When I want to use EntityFrameworkCore then if I do an update. For example, update every row of this table that has a type of "A" to have a name of "Type A", then how is that processed by EF?

```
public class Deck
{
    public string DeckGuid { get; set; } 
    public string Name     { get; set; }
    public string Type     { get; set; }   
}
```

Does EF retrieve or cause to be retrieved every row and then select those with Type = "A" and then update those one by one?

Also are there different ways I can code an update so that it doesn't do rows one by one for example if there are 1 million rows needing an update?

Also how about the case where just one row is getting updated and there is an index on the column Type.  Is any of this taken into account?

Comment: Cases where you want to update a great number of rows would be good scenarios to execute an SQL Statement directly via `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`.  You will want to ensure this is a Fresh DbContext in the sense that any cached entities the DbContext is tracking will not be updated, the change will go directly to the DB so any cached entities will need to be reloaded afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in [this](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions) EF extension. It's very useful when dealing with large amounts of data through EF.
Example for your update scenario (from their docs):

```
    //Delete
    context.Items.Where(a => a.ItemId >  500).BatchDelete();
    context.Items.Where(a => a.ItemId >  500).BatchDeleteAsync();

    // Update (using Expression arg.) supports Increment/Decrement 
    context.Items.Where(a => a.ItemId <= 500).BatchUpdate(a => new Item { Quantity = a.Quantity + 100 });
      // can be as value '+100' or as variable '+incrementStep' (int incrementStep = 100;)
      
    // Update (via simple object)
    context.Items.Where(a => a.ItemId <= 500).BatchUpdate(new Item { Description = "Updated" });
    context.Items.Where(a => a.ItemId <= 500).BatchUpdateAsync(new Item { Description = "Updated" });
    // Update (via simple object) - requires additional Argument for setting to Property default value
    var updateColumns = new List<string> { nameof(Item.Quantity) }; // Update 'Quantity' to default value('0'-zero)
    var q = context.Items.Where(a => a.ItemId <= 500);
    int affected = q.BatchUpdate(new Item { Description = "Updated" }, updateColumns);//result assigned to variable
```